# Load src of iframe using drop down menu and then change

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function newSrc() {
  var e = document.getElementById("MySelectMenu");
  var newSrc = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById("MyFrame").src=newSrc;
 }
</script>

<iframe name="content" src="" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 28px;" allowtransparency="true" border="0" scrolling="yes" width="100%" frameborder="0"     height="90%" id="MyFrame"></iframe>

<select id="MySelectMenu">
<option value="http://www.example.com">Example Site 1</option>
<option value="http://www.example2.com">Example Site 2</option>
</select>
<button onClick="newSrc();">Load Site</button>
```

This works well, it loads the source of the iframe depending on what option is selected from the menu. Now, what I'd like to do, after the option is chosen from the drop down and the Load Site button is clicked, is load the source from the option into the iframe, and then redirect the iframe ONCE after say...1 second.

So if Example Site 2 is chosen, the user clicks Load Site, http://www.example2.com is loaded, and the iframe is then redirected to http://www.example2.com/admin.

Thanks

Comment: I'm able to provide you with a solution. Do you mind using jQuery ?

Comment: @punkbit not at all, I don't mind. jQuery would be fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trying to help! Here's a solution (working example you can play with the code http://jsbin.com/cakuh/1/), it's just a sketch but you should understand what to do:

```
  <iframe name="content" src="" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 28px;" allowtransparency="true" border="0" scrolling="yes" width="100%" frameborder="0"     height="90%" id="MyFrame"></iframe>

  <select id="MySelectMenu">
  <option value="http://www.games.com">Games</option>
  <option value="http://www.bbc.com">BBC</option>
  </select>
  <button>Load Site</button>

$(function(){

  $('button').on('click', function(){
     var src = $("#MySelectMenu option:selected").attr('value'),
         myTimeout = null;  

    // first we de-attach and re-attach an event load
    $('iframe[name="content"]').off('load').on('load', function(){
     myTimeout = setTimeout(function(){

       clearTimeout(myTimeout);
       $('iframe[name="content"]').off('load');

       // you see, we concat '/admin' to the src
       $('iframe[name="content"]').attr('src', src + '/admin');

    }, 1000);        

    });

    // this will change the iframe src and load the page, triggering the iframe load event
    $('iframe[name="content"]').attr('src', src);

  });

});
```

Comment: Oh sorry, you want to then redirect to admin, I'll change the code in a bit, sorry a bit busy at the moment

Comment: ok the basic logic is there, but you need to improve it. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Absolutely bowled over by your efforts in trying to help...here's an extremely newbie question...where do I specify the source that the frame is redirected to after loading the initial source? Sorry...

Comment: Just seen your comments, yeah, a redirect would be awesome, thanks mate, when you get a minute :)

Comment: Ok I can comment the code, give a few seconds, but for the moment you'll notice that in the inner setTimout I just concat to the src a new string, you see src + '/admin' ?

Comment: ok added the comments, but didn't changed the live example you can copy the code there, should work fine.

Comment: I see that mate and that's awesome, working really well, I will mark your answer as correct shortly, one more thing. At the moment that is appending /admin to the end of the source...what if I wanted to change the source domain completely? Sorry, I know that's not what I asked, but then I can fully understand this. thanks.

Comment: On the inner setTimeout you can change src = "www.whatever.com"

Comment: I'm really bad at this aren't I... :( could you alter your code to reflect this rather than appending /admin to the source and I'll edit my question. Your help is amazing, thank you so much.

Comment: I figured it out mate, thank you very much :) answer will be accepted!

Comment: Oh wait...that is constantly reloading the iframe after 1 second...how do I make it just load the new source ONCE and then stop?

Comment: Sorry, just fixed that for you :)

Comment: You are amazing, works a treat! Thanks so much mate.